# DateTime Resets at midnight

Tags: c#, datetime

Hi I am using C# web app on visual studio.

I have written code to be able to distinguish if the time is between `6am-2pm` - `2pm-10pm` and `10pm - 6am`...

The code runs like a dream for the 6-2 - 2-10 times but for the 10pm - 6am.. the code runs fine until midnight and then it just resets my counter to 0 and stays at 0 until 6am.. I can't get my head around why this is doing.. Does anybody have a solution..

```
public DateTime Shiftstart { get; set; }

public DateTime Shiftend { get; set; }

public string Itemseriesmaster { get; set; }

public string SeriesMasterId { get; set; }

public void CalcShiftPeriod() //constructor
{
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now; //date time now
    int currentHour = now.Hour; //hour now
    int shiftHourStart;

    if (currentHour >= 6 && currentHour <= 13) 
    {
        shiftHourStart = 6;
    }
    else if  (currentHour >= 14 && currentHour <= 21)
    {
        shiftHourStart = 14;
    }
    else 
    {
        shiftHourStart = 22;
    }


    Shiftstart = now.Date.AddHours(shiftHourStart);
    Shiftend = Shiftstart.AddHours(7);
    Shiftend = Shiftend.AddMinutes(59);
    Shiftend = Shiftend.AddSeconds(59);
}
```

The code is calculating total units packed and is working fine, and resets after the given time on both the 6-2 and 2 - 10 shifts..

Until it gets to the 10pm - 6am and then just completely stops at midnight.

```
BizManager biz = new BizManager();

                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                    if (DDLProduct.SelectedValue.Equals("G120C-2") || DDLProduct.SelectedValue.Equals("G120 PM240-2") )
                    {
                        RefreshMainGridTht(selectedProduct, shiftStart, shiftEnd
                           );
                    }
                    dt = biz.GetPacktstatisticsForShift(shiftStart, shiftEnd, selectedProduct);

                    GridView1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
                    GridView1.DataBind();

                    int sumActual = 0;
                    int sumTarget = 0;


                    biz.CalculatePackingTotals(dt, out sumActual, out sumTarget);
                    LabelTotal.Text = sumActual.ToString();



                    DateTime dtmNow = DateTime.Now;
                    TimeSpan tsIntoShift = dtmNow - shiftStart;
                    TimeSpan tsTotalShift = shiftEnd - shiftStart;

                    double p = tsIntoShift.TotalMinutes / tsTotalShift.TotalMinutes;

                    int adjustedTarget = Convert.ToInt32(sumTarget * p);

                    if (sumActual > sumTarget)
                    {
                        LabelTotal.ForeColor = Color.Lime;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        LabelTotal.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ErrMsg = App.HandleError(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod(), ex, string.Empty);
```

Comment: the cause of the problem is not obvious from the code you posted, which looks fine for just determining the current shift. provide a minimal, complete example with which the problem you observe can be reproduced. maybe you need to offset -1 day from `now.Date` in the 22 hour case but that's hard to tell without context.

Comment: "The code is calculating total units packed and is working fine, and resets after the given" ... show this code as well

Comment: If i pass in some static date and times from a previous date, the shift 10pm-6am shows all of the figures correctly, but when its running live on the server it just resets to 0 at midnight and stays like that until 6am.

Comment: I use `public static bool TimeInRange(TimeSpan time, TimeSpan start, TimeSpan end)
        => (start <= end) ? time >= start && time <= end : time >= start || time <= end;` where `time` is datetime.TimeOfDay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to distinguish between `currentHour` from 0 to 5 and `currentHour` from 22 to 23.

For example, consider `currentHour` is 1. Your calculation says that the shift starts at 22:00 of the current day (`now.Date.AddHours(22)`), which is obviously wrong because the shift already started at 22:00 of the previous day.

So from `currentHour` 0 to 5 you have to subtract a day from your `Shiftstart`.

---

One possible way to do that would be to set `shiftHourStart` to `-2` for `currentHour` between 0 and 5.

```
if (currentHour < 6)
{
    shiftHourStart = -2;
}
else if (currentHour >= 6 && currentHour <= 13) 
{
    shiftHourStart = 6;
}
else if  (currentHour >= 14 && currentHour <= 21)
{
    shiftHourStart = 14;
}
else 
{
    shiftHourStart = 22;
}
```

Comment: Thanks i will also try this.

Comment: sorry for my lack of knowledge but what do i need to change in my code to get it too work like your suggestion?

Comment: @FelicityPerry You just prepend the if-Statement before the existing ones. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The error lies in adding the hours to the current day...

```
Shiftstart = now.Date.AddHours(shiftHourStart);
```

At 23:59 you are adding 22 hours to "2018-11-06".

One minute passes...

At 00:00 you are adding 22 hours to "2018-11-07".

That means your start time moves 24 hours over the course of that one minute.

You could distinguish this scenario as part of your if-statement. See the comments a) and b) below.

```
        int currentHour = now.Hour;
        DateTime date = now.Date; // a) This is today in most cases...

        int shiftHourStart;

        if (currentHour >= 6 && currentHour <= 13)
        {
            shiftHourStart = 6;
        }
        else if (currentHour >= 14 && currentHour <= 21)
        {
            shiftHourStart = 14;
        }
        else if (currentHour >= 22)
        {
            shiftHourStart = 22;
        }
        else
        {
            // midnight to 6am
            date = date.AddDays(-1); // b) But not in this case
            shiftHourStart = 22;
        }
```

Comment: Thank you guys for all of your responses, i will try this method above. I guess i will have to wait until midnight comes until i can test this?

Comment: " I guess i will have to wait until midnight comes until i can test this? " it's time to test. You can create Date time with the hours you want.

Answer (score 0):

First store your time in a `TimeSpan` this will give you more flexibility if tomorrow shift start and ends at 30min. Then store those `Timespan` in a class that represent the time frame. And if you have a list of them make it a List. It will help reading and maintaining your code. For now it's a brunch of magic numbers.

To check if a time is in a Range, I used :

```
public static bool IsBetween(TimeSpan time, TimeSpan start, TimeSpan end)
    => (start <= end) ? time >= start && time <= end : time >= start || time <= end;


internal void TestMethod()
{
    var timeSlots = new[] {
        new TimeFrame { start= new TimeSpan(6,0,0) , end = new TimeSpan(13,0,0) },
        new TimeFrame { start= new TimeSpan(14,0,0) , end = new TimeSpan(21,0,0) },
        new TimeFrame { start= new TimeSpan(22,0,0) , end = new TimeSpan(6,0,0) }
    };

    var today = DateTime.Today;
    var dayHours = Enumerable.Range(0, 24).Select(x => today.AddHours(x)).ToList();

    foreach (var currentDateTime in dayHours)
    {
        var matchingRanges = timeSlots.Where(x => IsBetween(currentDateTime .TimeOfDay, x.start, x.end));
        if (matchingRanges.Any())
        {
            var temp = matchingRanges.First();
            Console.WriteLine($"-> {currentDateTime } is in range {temp.start}-{temp.end}");                
            Console.WriteLine($"\t ShiftHours= {temp.start}-{temp.end.Subtract(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1))}");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"no Match for {currentDateTime }");
        }
    }
}
```

As you added a comment about testing it at midnight , included a TestMethod where I create all hours of a day (from 00h to 23h) so you can easly see what going on.

Comment: @FelicityPerry, 
As you add issue for testing, I have a question is this code clear enought? Do I need to format the IsBetween logic with and if/else instead or a ternary? Is the LinQ clear?